# CentOS 7 - Install Paramiko - bash: paramiko: command not found... error

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I am new to Python and CentOS and looking for some options to automate some daily job using Paramiko.

However, got below error when installing Paramiko. Hope you guys can help.

```
[jason@centos7 ~]$ sudo pip install paramiko
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting paramiko
  Using cached paramiko-2.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (206 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko) (3.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.5 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version < "3" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.5->paramiko) (1.0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.5->paramiko) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko) (2.14)
Installing collected packages: paramiko
Successfully installed paramiko-2.7.1
[jason@centos7 ~]$
[jason@centos7 ~]$
[jason@centos7 ~]$
[jason@centos7 ~]$
**[jason@centos7 ~]$ paramiko --version
bash: paramiko: command not found...**
[jason@centos7 ~]$
[jason@centos7 ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
[jason@centos7 ~]$
```

Tried to add the path into system path - still no luck

```
[jason@centos7 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/jason/.local/bin:/home/jason/bin:/usr/:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: you should at the first install paramiko : pip3 install paramiko , on your centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `paramiko` shell command.

Paramiko is Python module. You have to write Python code to make use of it.

For some examples, see [Paramiko demos](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/main/demos).